# Update large table in Rails without locking the table for extended period

Tags: sql

I have 1000s of `email` in a large `users` table with invalid email addresses that end in ".c" instead of ".com". How does one go about changing these emails to ".com" in a batch SQL query? I'm trying to write a migration that will fix all of these emails in batches so that I don't lock the database.

Here's what I have so far:

```
select 
     email 
from 
     users 
where 
     email like '%.c'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: maybe instead of changing the db, change the model?

Comment: I did change the model to have some validations but I still have bad data in the database.

Comment: @Jwan622 the model could interpret the bad data and present `.com` whenever `.c` is encountered. Or if you are really worried about performance, you could update each record opportunistically, not all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your field's length is enough and try this:

```
update users
   set email = concat(email,'om')
 where
 email like '%.c'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update users
     set email = replace(email, '.c', '.com')
where
     email like '%.c'
```